# rails 3 - FactoryGirl create associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, factory-bot

I am trying to create some test data to fill my tables with so that i can test functionality on my site.

The tables in question are: `songs`, `song_arrangements`, and `song_arrangement_files`.  The are associated in this way.

```
Songs:
    has_many :song_arrangements, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :song_arrangement_files, :through => :song_arrangements

Song Arrangements:
    belongs_to :song
    has_many :song_arrangement_files, :dependent => :destroy

Song Arrangement Files:
    belongs_to :song
    belongs_to :song_arrangement
```

I have been able to create 25 songs with FactoryGirl with this code:

```
Code in my spec file:
    before { FactoryGirl.create_list(:song, 25) }

Code in the factory:
    FactoryGirl.define do
        factory :song do |s|
            s.sequence(:title) { |n| "Song Title #{n}" }
            s.sequence(:artist) { |n| "Song Artist #{n}" }
        end
    end
```

Any thoughts on how to create `song_arrangements` and `song_arrangement_files` that are correctly assciated with their respective `song_arrangement` or `song` record?

I'm guessing i could use `after(:create)` nested in my factory somehow.  I'm very new to FactoryGirl and still fairly new to Rails in general.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if it matters but i am using rspec for my tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my other answer helped me do what i needed to do; however, i was needing to basically go one level of associations deeper and i was hitting walls with that solution.  I ended re-reading the FactoryGirl documentation for associations and came up with this solution that works in all my cases.  It creates songs, song_arrangements, and song_arrangement_files.  I'm sure the code isn't pretty, but it works and can be improved upon later.  Hope this helps anyone running into the same type of roadblocks.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :song do |s|
    s.sequence(:title) { |n| "Song Title #{n}" }
    s.sequence(:artist) { |n| "Song Artist #{n}" }

    factory :song_with_song_arrangements do
      ignore do
        song_arrangements_count 100
      end

      after(:create) do |song, evaluator|
        FactoryGirl.create_list(:song_arrangement, evaluator.song_arrangements_count, song: song)
      end
    end
  end

  factory :song_arrangement do |sa|
    song

    sa.sequence(:title) { |n| "Arrangement #{n}" }
    original_key 'A'
    bpm 75
    sa.sequence(:chart_content) { |n| "This is the chart content for Arrangement #{n}." }
    chart_mapping 'V1, C, V2, C, B, C, C'
    sa.sequence(:notes) { |n| "These are notes for the Arrangement #{n}." }

    factory :song_arrangement_with_song_arrangement_files do
      ignore do
        song_arrangement_files_count 100
      end

      after(:create) do |song_arrangement, evaluator|
        FactoryGirl.create_list(:song_arrangement_file, evaluator.song_arrangement_files_count, song_arrangement: song_arrangement)
      end
    end
  end

  factory :song_arrangement_file do |saf|
    song_arrangement
    song

    saf.sequence(:title) { |n| "Attachment #{n}" }
    url 'http://www.google.com'
    saf.sequence(:description) { |n| "This is the description of Attachment #{n}." }
  end
end
```

Code used to call these factories:

```
Songs:
    before(:each) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:song, 25) }
Song Arrangements:
    before(:each) { FactoryGirl.create(:song_with_song_arrangements) }
Song Arrangement Files:
    before(:each) { FactoryGirl.create(:song_arrangement_with_song_arrangement_files) }
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else running in to this issue, here's the solution i came up with.  As i said, i am new to FactoryGirl so if there's a better way to do this please share!

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :song do |s|
    s.sequence(:title) { |n| "Song Title #{n}" }
    s.sequence(:artist) { |n| "Song Artist #{n}" }

    before(:create) do |song|
      song.song_arrangements << FactoryGirl.build_list(:song_arrangement, 10)
    end
  end

  factory :song_arrangement do |sa|
    sa.sequence(:title) { |n| "Arrangement #{n}" }
    original_key 'A'
    bpm 75
    sa.sequence(:chart_content) { |n| "This is the chart content for Arrangement #{n}." }
    chart_mapping 'V1, C, V2, C, B, C, C'
    sa.sequence(:notes) { |n| "These are notes for the Arrangement #{n}." }
  end
end
```

Giving credit where credit is due, i actually found the answer after a lot of searching from this post: [How to user factory girl to create associated lists with a has_many with a validation that requires it on create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421200/how-to-user-factory-girl-to-create-associated-lists-with-a-has-many-with-a-valid?rq=1)

It was Blizzo's answer that i pulled the solution from.